# how to treat tied condition in ndcg calculation?

Tags: recommender-system, ranking, ndcg

I am trying to calculate ndcg manually, and not sure how to treat tied condition.

For example, item A, B, C, D, the actual rating is 1, 0, 0,0. Should irank = 1,2,3,4. or 1,2,2,2, or 1,3,3,3?